# Wireshark - Capture AUTH&ASSOC packets from connected AP

Tags: authentication, wireshark, packet-capture, wifi

Im currently trying to capture all packets of a WiFi connect procedure (Authentication, Association, EAPOL and Deauthentication) on a machine.

Im starting Wireshark and start capturing on wlan0, but as soon as i try to connect on the same machine with my Test AP im getting a message that the interface is closed. When im using the any interface i only get the 4 EAPOL Key messages but i need all 4 above mentioned messages.

We need to do this too proof that another AP is sending deauth messages and not our device (Capturing stack of the connecting client)

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer is answered by another rather  hidden post:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130716/how-to-sniff-802-11-packets-without-going-into-monitor-mode?rq=1

https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

Keyword: -y IEEE802_11 which my nic wifi doesnt support.